# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTransform' of null when using Openlayers and Jest + Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, openlayers

Currently using the OpenLayers ExtentInteraction and when I run my tests I manage to get the error as run test with jest:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTransform' of null
```

with the following code:

```js
import ExtentInteraction from 'ol/interaction/Extent';

new ExtentInteraction({
  // option
});
```

[image: Error Below]

Any suggestions as it's getting late and I'm weary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `jsdom` browser doesn't support `canvas` API so in order to fix this you can install this dev dependency `jest-canvas-mock` to add `canvas` api to `jsdom` window. Here is a few steps:

Install:

```sh
yarn add -D jest-canvas-mock

// or npm

npm i -D jest-canvas-mock
```

Add this package as your `setupFiles` of `jest`:

```js
{
  setupFiles: ['jest-canvas-mock']
}
```

That's it!